# laravel moltin custom user authentication

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, moltin

I'm building a store with laravel and wondered if I'm going about this the right way. I think I need to handle user authentication myself, as I want users to be able to sign up with their social media accounts. This is the way I'm thinking....

User signs up on my store, this creates a user in my database. The server would then submit a post request via CURL to create a moltin customer and randomly generate a moltin password which can be stored against the user in my db.

On the client, the user gets an jwt access token to verify them against the users in my DB. I guess the issue is each request on the server would then have to get the moltin password from the user in the database, get an access token, and then do any requests each time an api request is made which is going to require several requests per request made by the user. I suppose I could also store the moltin token on the client, pass it to the server and then I'd only need to get the moltin token if it's expired/not there.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

*disclosure, I'm an engineer at moltin*

If you're talking about customers on a single store (as opposed to a separate store per user) and you're using PHP to build your store, then you don't need to worry about storing moltin login credentials for each user. You can access their data using their customer ID.

You'd store their moltin customer ID alongside their other data in your DB and once they've authenticated on your site using their social media account, there'd be no need to authenticate again on the moltin side, just use the matching ID.